# Using external javascript code to add effects to a GWT generated page

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to add an external javascript code to add some effects to the gwt generated part of the page.

I was provided with some static html/css from the designer, and it uses javascript to add the desired effects to the page.

Our app uses MVP architecture as described on the official GWT pages, so for the initial test I just put the static html into an *UiBinder* xml file of a desired view. The output was nice, and the page looked the same as the provided one when opened in the browser. The only problem is that the javascript effects don't work.

Specifically, it is the accordion effect of the Rico framework. When a mouse is over a list element, it should change colour. And when a user clicks on the list element, it expands to show more details (like a tree widget).

The script inclusion in the module's host page looks like this:

```
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="javascript/rico.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        Rico.loadModule('Accordion');
        Rico.onLoad( function() {
          new Rico.Accordion( $$('div.panelheader'), $$('div.panelContent'),
                              {panelHeight:66, hoverClass: 'mdHover', selectedClass: 'mdSelected'});
        });
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
```

All of the *.js* files that were provided by the designer are in the `war/javascript` folder, and when inspected in firebug (in both development mode and tomcat deployed), the browser seems to see those files. I can click on the `src="../...js"` and the browser does open the correct files.

Where could the problem be? Since the static page works and the effects are visible, i suppose the problem was in the merge with the GWT. Did I do something wrong with the inclusion, or is the external javascript having problem with accesing the gwt generated parts of the page?

Comment: Might be a timing issue that the gwt hasn't added its element to the page when your js function tries to add the effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases I go the other way round - I call a JS function defined in the host page (just wrap what you have in the `<script>` tags in a function) from my GWT code via JSNI function (usually in `onModuleLoad`). The JSNI function would look something like this:

```
public final native void initRico() /*-{
    $wnd.ricoInitFunction();
}-*/;
```

Oh, and are you sure that `$$('div.panelheader')` actually gets that element? If you are using UiBinder and define styles in `<ui:style>` tags, then they will get obfuscated (`<ui:style>` is converted to a `CssResource` at compile time). If you want to be sure you are using the right elements, you can easily pass a GWT `Widget` to your init function - just use the `getElement()` method:

```
public final native void initRico(Element e1, Element e2) /*-{
    $wnd.ricoInitFunction(e1, e2);
}-*/;

// The actual call would then look like this:
initRico(widget1.getElement(), widget2.getElement());
```

Then use those elements in your code:

```
function ricoInitFunction(e1, e2) {
    Rico.loadModule('Accordion');
    Rico.onLoad( function() {
    new Rico.Accordion( $$(e1), $$(e2),
        {panelHeight:66, hoverClass: 'mdHover', selectedClass: 'mdSelected'});
    });
}
```

Either way, you shouldn't try to "query" the elements you need, you should keep track of them as `Widget`s. Use the OO facilities that Java provides - that's one of the main reasons I use GWT :)

Comment: THX. Of course, it was a rookie mistake. The problem was as you and pathed noticed. The elements in question weren't created in time of calling the new Accordion(), and therefore weren't added. The style was OK so i didn't need the parametrized function, but anyway thx for a good idea. The final solution was to call the native function to init the accordian after the presenter already added the view to the page.